# Going to another Fragment while in a Fragment

Tags: android, eclipse, fragment, android-fragmentactivity

Hi there in my Fragment Activity I can control what page I want my Fragment to be on as below

```
mIndicator.setCurrentItem(mAdapter.getCount() - 1);
```

But in my Fragment I would like to go into another I have realised this code will not work is there any solution to this problem ?

Comment: Do you want to make is so that you move from one fragment to another (the initial fragment is not visible) or open a second fragment on top of the first?

Answer (score 0):

Please, be more specific when you ask a question. It's difficult to answer when we don't know how is written your code..

First of all you MUST read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html, will teach you the basics of fragment in Android.

Anyway, if I understand correctly, you need a `FrameLayout`, to fit the bill. Below the example:

```
<FrameLayout 
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Secondly, in your Java code, you need to type this:

```
Fragment mfragment = new yourDummyFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager(); // The support android library
FragmentTransaction mtransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction(); // Initialize the    transaction
mtransaction.replace(R.id.xmlOfYourFragment, mfragment);
mtransaction.commit(); // The change starts.
```